# How to sort nested populated field in MongoDB (Mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I am trying to sort populated array based on the nested and populated field using mongoose but it is not working.

Here are my modals.

```
const campaignSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    prospects: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Prospect" }],
  }
);

const prospectSchema = new Schema(
  { 
    strategy: { type: String, trim: true },
    contact: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Contact", required: true }, 
    primaryCaller: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Contact" }, 
  }
);

const contactSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  }
);
```

Now I am trying to populate **prospects** and **contact in each prospect** in and sort them by **contact.firstName** using the following code.

```
const campaign = await Campaign.findOne({ _id: id }).populate({
  path: "prospects",
  populate: [
    { path: "contact", select: "firstName lastName" },
    { path: "primaryCaller", select: "firstName lastName" },
  ],
  options: {
    sort: "contact.firstName",
  },
}).lean();
```

I tested it with `sort: "strategy",` and it is working fine with it.

I also tried Aggregations but it also didn't help.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/d564362f9d45ae731cf63e9e6d8359bd2fd05661/index.d.ts#L1212 says "sort" should be within population parameters object. Must be something like `{ path: "contact", select: "firstName lastName", options: { sort: {"firstName ": 1 } } },`

Comment: Yes, but I want to sort **prospects** not contact.

Comment: Are you saying prospects are not sorted either? `sort: "contact.firstName"` should work even if object within `contacts` remain unsorted. Can you provide an example to reproduce the problem?